# How read and wrtie text files by spark with parittions?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

There some text files which are place into directory structure like:

```
date=2022-01-01/client-id=xxx/
```

It is needed to read then filter out some lines and perform write to the same structure like. But method `saveAsTextFile` do not have any partitions, also text file have only single string column (as I understand). So is there a way to read text files with partitioning and output them with same partition structure?

P.S. question is about normal spark solution, not about listing all fodlers and iterate over all of them manually in the code

Answer (score 0):

The method named `partitionBy(colNames : _root_.scala.Predef.String*)` from DataFrameWriter should create the output structure you need.

Usage example:

```
  df.write
    .format("json")
    .mode("overwrite")
    .partitionBy("date", "client-id")
    .save(outputPath)
```

You can use any structured output format, e.g. delta, parquet, csv, json, etc. Text format is not compatible, you'll see the following exception in this case

```
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Text data source supports only a single column, and you have n columns.;
```

This limitation makes sense and it is a good practice to store processed data in a structured format.